# Understanding SIP trunks

Tags: sip, voip, trunk

I've recently been loking into SIP trunks and VoIP tecnology. However, I don't fully understand what is the role of SIP trunks is.

To my understanding, VoIP technology works by sending pakets over the internet, and with a VoIP service porvider, the parkets are sent to their destinations. In case the destination is a landline number, a sip trunk must be used. However, i dont get what part does it play. Is it a software component? If so, is it something the business using VoIP must implement? Is it something only the business pays and the provideer conects voice calls to the PTSN? Or i dont get if it is a phyiscal component, that is necessary to conect the business to the VoIP provide.

Any insight in this matter is greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've recently been loking into SIP trunks and VoIP tecnology. However,
> I don't fully understand what is the role of SIP trunks is.

It is a common and recurring problem with SIP trunking, you are not alone.

Your understanding of VOIP is correct but this will not help you to understand trunks.

Trunk is a concept inherited of TDM telecom network, it was in the beginning a certain number of twisted copper wire pairs molded in one big cable and latter with PCM introduction any cable that multiplex communication.
So you have trunk between ethernet-switches or between enterprise PBX or between carriers (telco service provider) and so on ...

In you question, you are talking about SIP **Public** Trunking, this is the same commercial offer than the older TDM ISDN connection so basically it is a ISDN replacement with the same basic service.

In term of SIP, the trunk provides a point of registration (REGISTRAR), authentication, billing and basic call features ; in summary a kind of SIP edge proxy/registrar